# ERROR 1160 (08S01) at line 1: Got an error writing communication packet federated

Tags: mysql, federated-table

On one of our mysql servers we have a federated table populated by a query on another server.

SELECT queries on this table randomly give this error :

```
ERROR 1160 (08S01) at line 1: Got an error writing communication packet
```

Usually it happens once then it works for hours and then shows again once.

It looks like a timeout on because of cold table. But I don't know how to check my guess and how to solve it.

- The server that host the federated table is : Ver
  8.0.33-0ubuntu0.20.04
- The queried server to populate the table is : Ver
  8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04

I found things on stack about communication packet errors but only one related to federated tables (and it has no useful answer and was posted years ago).